# Source data type [geometry] not supported

Tags: mysql, postgresql, database-migration, navicat, mysql-spatial

I am using Navicat Premium to Migrate my Data from Postgresql to Mysql.

I am facing a strang error while migration. It says that Migration is not possible due to Geometry object not available.

I am pasting the logs here..

```
[Msg] [Dtf] DataTransfer started
[Msg] [Dtf] Getting tables properties
[Msg] [Dtf] Getting tables fields
[Msg] [Dtf] Getting tables constraints
[Msg] [Dtf] Getting tables indexes
[Msg] [Dtf] Getting total records count
[Msg] [Dtf] Drop table: `geom_data`
[Err] [Dtf] 80120001: Source data type [geometry] not supported
[Err] [Dtf] Finished - Unsuccessfully
--------------------------------------------------
```

What could be the problem.. Can I migrate Postgresql Spatial data to MySql?? Any alternative? Any way out??

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a datatype "geometry" and you can't create it either. Migrating spatial data from PostgreSQL to MySQL is a huge step back, are you sure you need/want this?

Comment: You'd probably need to get the Navicat folks to add support for PostGIS and MySQL Spatial. It doesn't seem to be supported by the tool at this time. Personally I can't imagine why you'd want to, but sometimes the technical requirements aren't the only factors...

Comment: Yes, I do need it.. 90 % of the data is in MySql and I need to migrate rest of the 10% from Postgres.. :(

Comment: @CraigRinger.. Yes you are right.. I've found the solution using another tool.. Will post the answer very soon.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Task can be done through [SQLyog's](https://www.webyog.com/product/downloads) data Migration wizard.

```
SQLYog-->Powertools-->Import External Data-->Start A new Job-->
```

- After that select `Any ODBC Source` from the radio Buttons
- Select `File DSN---> Create a New DSN--File Data Source-->PostgreSQL Unicode`
- Click Next and `save the file anywhere`. eg abc.dsn
- Click next and `enter postgresql details` and click finish
- `Enter the MySql database details` you wanna copy your data into.
- You are ready to go.

Hope it helps.!

**Note:** If Postgresql contains geometrical data, please make sure that you are using `MyISAM` as the database engine in MySql. Also `remove indexing on any geometrical element` before copying.